# Handling multiple primary keys

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have multiple tables, most of them have integer primary key. Is it a bad practice If I put all tables to `identity(1,1)` ?

I have thinking about this to be able to distinguish:

- `identity(1000,1)` for the **users** table
- `identity(100000,1)` for the **employees**
- `identity(20000,1)` for **leave_request**
- for `leave_given_id` (in **leave_given** table), It's not going to be automatic increment but I'll take the `leave_request_id` and add 2 to the left. (or 200000). In other words, I will have 220001 in `leave_given_id` If `leave_request_id` is 20001

and so on..

Does it make sense to do that?

Comment: Why do you want all IDs to be unique accross different tables? You can have repeated IDs amongst different entities, *as long as you don't join them up*.

Comment: @EzLo  Just felt like It's more appropriate to have unique numbers so the user of the application won't be confused.

Comment: @EzLo *as long as you don't join them up* Why join? Union maybe?

Comment: *the user of the application won't be confused* I don't know the reason for to show synthetic IDs to users at all. That fields have no practical meaning for them.

Comment: If you want really to exclude equality - use step value more than 1 and proper initial values. For example `identity(1,4)` for users, `identity(2,4)` for employees, `identity(3,4)` for leave_request, and `identity(4,4)` as a reserve.

Comment: @Akina is right, the fields have no practical meaning to them, also I would like to point out that defining it in this way you lose half of your integer range. Best to define them like identity(-2147483648,1)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; firstly no it doesn't make sense to do that, secondly you can do that and the application wont care / notice either way

The main thing that you are fighting with confusing is human interaction, So as far as any application is concerned you should have the `user_id`, `employee_id` and a `leave_request_id`, any application when coded correctly will be able to identify the differences,

Looking at it, would it not be easier to have a `person` table (I'm presuming here that `users` are external to your employee list.

From here you could have a person and all their details in that table, with the identity field on it, and then if they are a user that entry is added into that table, if they are an employee they are entered into that table, (if both then both tables) and finally if an employee leaves they can be added into that table.

Now you have one id across all of your tables which makes joining them together a lot easier if you need to look at any users who are employees who have left you have a single ID across all tables, it also means that from a human perspective the ID you know what it all is in relation to because its all the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a bad practice If I put all tables to identity(1,1) ?

No it is not a bad practice. But what you are tying to do is bad practice.

IMO Technical people do not need to distinguish between different ids.It is very clear to them. However as per `biz requirement` you can create user friendly ID/code for Users to view in UI Level/reports. For example `Employee code` in particular format ,like "`00001`".These columns should be in separate column and do not participate in join or where conditions. They are only for display purpose. That too not all table or all UI need these `Synthetic code`

> Other points

1. Defining it in this way identity(100000,1 )   you lose half of your integer range.

Comment: "Defining it in this way identity(100000,1 ) you lose `0.0046%` of your integer range."

Comment: an integer range is from -2147483648 to 2147483648 so you lose at least 50%